# Get width and height of display assign it to static integer

Tags: android

I am new to android developing please help me in this problem.

```
static Display display=((WindowManager)context
       .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();  
static int height=display.getHeight();  
static int width=display.getWidth();
```

This shows error so give me solution.

> 11-26 17:40:17.806: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: why you are making it static?

Comment: I am passing this value to another class. i wrote this code in activity.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
public static int width = display.getWidth();
public static int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: but,i want value in static integer. this doesn't help me.

Comment: you can assign it, only take int variable as static.
see edited answer

Comment: this doesn't help. it require display to be static.

Comment: why you want display as static? i mean requirement

Comment: i don't want but eclipse require.

Answer (score 0):

you can Try this for Get Height-width and dpi

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        dpi = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
```